# failed to connect to unix domain socket on os x

Tags: c, macos, sockets

I am trying to connect to unix domain socket created by another process.
here is what i am doing. the file is exists on the file system when I running it.

```
socketFd = socket(AF_UNIX, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
if (socketFd < 0) {
    socketFd = -1;

    return -1;
}

bzero(&address, sizeof(struct sockaddr_un));
address.sun_family = AF_UNIX;

size_t address_length = sizeof(address.sun_family) + 
                        sprintf(address.sun_path, "/tmp/%s", COMMON_SOCKET);

connect(socketFd, (struct sockaddr *)&address, address_length);
```

i got error and errno is ENOENT. but doing ls on /tmp show me the file is there.

what do i do wrong ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're confused about `address_length`. It should simply be:

```
size_t address_length = sizeof(address);
```

or really just:

```
connect(socketFd, (struct sockaddr *)&address, sizeof(address));
```

Answer (score 0):

Since your on Mac OS X, you can try:

`socketFD = socket(PF_LOCAL, SOCK_STREAM, 0);`

PF_UNIX is deprecated on Snow Leopard.  Not sure about AF_UNIX on Mac OS (at least the socket man page doesn't show it).

Comment: there is struct sockaddr_un. it is defined on sys/un.h